# I don't want to select hidden element, How can I do that?

Tags: jquery

I am using a JQuery Plugin, which uses following line

```
var inputSelector = 'input[class]:not(:button|:submit|:reset), textarea[class], select[class]';
```

It select some element.

It also selects the hidden element, how can I achieve that without giving any class to hidden element?

And It must work in IE.

Comment: You should probably clarify if you mean an input of `type="hidden"` or one that is not visible.

Comment: @Box9 : yes its <input type="hidden" ..../>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the not() method on the array returned by the selector.

```
var inputSelector = 'input[class]:not(:button|:submit|:reset), textarea[class], select[class]';
var controls = $(inputSelector).not('[type="hidden"]');
```

This filters the hidden elements out of the array returned by the selector.

Comment: thanks. Its working. But is there any way to add anything to inpuSelector not adding to controls

Answer (score 1):

took me a minute but figured it out [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/Vbw6c/)

sorry it didn't save right

**EDIT**
now with no class

here is the html

```
<input type="text" name="foo" />
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="bar" value="surprise" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

here is the jQuery

```
var inputSelector = 'input:not(:button, :submit, :reset,:hidden), textarea, select';
$(inputSelector).val('foobar');
var bc = $('#bar').val();
alert(bc);
```

The alert should say "surprise" because the hidden element with id "bar" is not selected

Comment: this i specific to particular class. I don't want to use class. I don't what classes can be there.

Comment: @mcgrailm : how can you say, its not selecting hidden element.

Comment: @Gaurav holy crap I need more coffee new fiddle modified link in post

Comment: +1 I hope you don't mind me copying the example from jsfiddle into here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputSelector = 'input[class]:not(:button|:submit|:reset|:hidden), textarea[class], select[class]';
```

Will not select hidden elements as well.